# OpenWeatherMap Forecast Min/Max Temperature Hole Day Forecast

Tags: php, openweathermap

I try to use the foreach loop to display only the next min. and max. (of whole day) temperatures for the next 3 days. But I can only read them out so that it gives me min. max. Temperatures in 3h interval for the actual and the coming 4 days.

But it should be like this:
**Thursday 15.09:** Max: 25°C/Min: 20°C
**Friday 16.09:** Max: 23°C/Min: 14°C
**Saturday 17.09:** Max: 20°C/Min: 10°C

```
$api_forecast   = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=berlin,DE,DE&appid='.$api_key;
$forecast_data  = json_decode( file_get_contents($api_forecast),  true);
echo '<table><tbody>';

foreach ($forecast_data['list'] as $val) {
  $f_temp         = round($val['main']['day'] - 273.15) . '°C';
  $f_date         = date($dateFormat , strtotime($val['dt_txt']));
  $f_pressure     = $val['pressure'];
  $f_humidity     = $val['humidity'];
  $f_wind_speed   = $val['wind']['speed'];
  $f_wind_dir     = $val['wind']['deg'];
  $f_clouds       = $val['clouds']['all'];
  $f_weather      = $val['weather'][0];
  $f_main         = $val['main'];
  $f_icon         = $val['icon'];
  $f_max_temp     = round($val['main']['temp_max'] - 273.15) . '°C';
  $f_min_temp     = round($val['main']['temp_min'] - 273.15) . '°C';

  echo  '<tr><td><strong>' . $f_date . ':</strong></td><td>Max:' .  $f_max_temp . '</td><td>/Min:' .  $f_min_temp . '</td></tr>';
}

echo '</tbody></table>';
```

Comment: a side note (rather important), i don't think its wise to share your `APP ID` publicly, it is included in the `API URL`. I think this should be kept secret.

Comment: Thank you, I removed it!

Comment: You should revoke it as well. It still visible in the history

Comment: Yes indeed, i strongly recommend @ClémentBaconnier suggestion.

Comment: I just deleted the api on openweathermap.

Answer (score 0):

With the right parameters when calling the Openweathermap API, you can save yourself a lot of work ( [more](https://openweathermap.org/forecast16#geocoding) ).

```
$maxDays = 3;
$query = http_build_query(array(
  'q' => 'Berlin,DE,DE',
  'cnt' => $maxDays,
  'mode' => 'json',
  'units' => 'metric',
  'lang' => 'de',
  'appid' => $apiId,
));
$url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?'.$query;
$json = file_get_contents($url);
```

You get your temperatures by the day in a form that you can easily output:

```
  //:
  'list' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'dt' => 1663239600,
      'sunrise' => 1663216817,
      'sunset' => 1663262596,
      'temp' => 
      array (
        'day' => 15.48,
        'min' => 12.62,
        'max' => 18.45,
        'night' => 12.78,
        'eve' => 16.02,
        'morn' => 13.19,
      ),
```